Why am I not getting any strawberry yeild from my garden?
I have a raised vegetable box.
I have had tomatoes, peppers and strawberries in year past.
This year the strawberries have over taken the box.  So I decided to go with just strawberries and a few tomatoes.
I got one little tasty strawberry in June.
So far there are no buds on the plants.
What can I do?




I would say: weather (or location: e.g. not much sun). Plants seems healthy and strong. Now with runners they are behaving as end of season vegetative reproduction.
